# Sqlite3 rowid vs. AUTOINCREMTENT

Tags: sqlite, auto-increment, rowid

Im working on my second project with sqlite3 and have a question.

What is the difference between working with rowid and/or working with own AUTOINCREMENT INTEGER value?

Is one of both better/faster than the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Sqlite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) the difference is that the `rowid` can be reassigned, while an `AUTOINCREMENT INTEGER` can not.

To quote the important part:

> (T)he use of AUTOINCREMENT requires additional work to be done as each row is inserted and thus causes INSERTs to run a little slower.